# osm overpass query by country

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, iso-3166

I am using this Overpass query to extract all coworking amenities in Italy.

```
( area["ISO3166-1"="IT"];) ->.a;
        node["amenity"="coworking_space"]
          (area.a);
         (._;>;);
 out body;
```

If I try to do the same for France using FR as ISO3166 country code

```
( area["ISO3166-1"="FR"];) ->.a;
        node["amenity"="coworking_space"]
          (area.a);
         (._;>;);
 out body;
```

I get no results while I am sure there are nodes like that in France (i tested with a separate query using automatic bbox).

Question:

- Am I getting wrong the ISO3166 country code of France?
- In general, there is a better way to extract osm data from overpass by country?

Thanks,

Jacopo

Answer (score 3):

You should query for the key `ISO3166-1:alpha2` or `ISO3166-1:alpha3` and use `ISO3166-1` only as a fallback. These keys are explained in the [country code](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Country_code) wiki page.

The [relation for the state of Italy](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/365331) has tag `ISO3166-1` while  the [relation for the state of France](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2202162) doesn't. But both have the value you are looking for in the `ISO3166-1:alpha2` key.